# Password not working / changes after update from COS 12.1 to Cyanogen OS 13

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, encryption, password, oneplus-one

I've encrypted my OnePlus One a long time ago. Now I want to perform the update with the new released Cyanogen OS 13. The problem is that the phone don't want to validate the password from the previous version. The pin or pattern works perfectly in TWRP (v2.8.x). By booting with COS 13 it isn't working anymore. After a flashing the old COS version the password or pattern is working fine. I've changed the pin several times and also tried to use the lock pattern but there is no difference. Has someone a clue how to fix this problem. I don't want to set up the whole OS again. Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm as well as try the approach noted here: https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/cos13-update-does-not-work-for-encrypted-phones.441637/page-2#post-14802297?

Comment: That's exactly my problem. Thanks a lot! Sadly there is not solution yet: https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/BACON-4671

Comment: I also tried the 4x4 pattern -> Same problem!